# get heatmap analytics data for apps using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, heatmap

Basically I need to find the portions of my app page where the maximum clicks has been fetched..The graphical form of it is heatmap which brightens up the area where the users clicked the most.CrazyEgg is one tool which has heatmap but it basically does for website,I need to find the analytics on my app.There is one 'uservod' but it gets the heatmap only for iOS apps.I need it for both android and iOS.Please let me know if there are any such tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at "Tealeaf CX Mobile" (IBM). 
But be aware that it might be a little expensive.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Tealeaf On Cloud has an analytics module, called Overstat, which basically gives you exactly this ability. You can view clicks and all sorts of other actions in a heatmap over the webpage in question, and create subsegments to understand the user activity going on in your application.

Comment: Please avoid signatures in your posts, it may be considered spam by the community. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own website, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be using the link only when relevant as a reference and including the majority of the content here.